# Eigenvalues of the matrix representation of a complex number?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Let $M$ be the matrix representation of a complex number:

$$
M=\pmatrix{a&b\\-b&a} \implies \det M=a^2+b^2
$$

My question is what do the eigenvalues of $M$ represent?

$$
det(sI-M)=0 \implies s = \{a + ib, a- ib\}
$$

For reference the eigenvectors are $v=\{ (i,1), (-i,1)\}$

---

The standard interpretation of the eigenvalues is that they represent the stretch of the linear transformation along the eigenbasis. But I am at a loss as to how to visualize this in the case of complex numbers. What is the linear transformation is this case: is M a transformation from the origin (0,0) to position (a,b) on the complex plane? If this is the case, why are we getting two vectors if the point (a,b) goes to a single position on the plane?

Comment: You question is interesting but not quite precise. You should distinguish between a complex number (which is a scalar)

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I do not understand your request.

Comment: Sorry, I was interrupted while writing. You should distinguish between a complex number (which is a scalar) and the matrix $M$ which is a _real_ $2\times2$ matrix. It is the matrix of _multiplication by a complex number_ as a real-linear transformation, expressed on a particular basis of the complex plane viewed as real vector space. Note that $M$ cannot be a transformation from the origin to $(a,b)$, since every linear transformation fixes the origin. Finally (but less importantly) it is more customary to have the coefficient $-b$ on the top right, in other words transpose the matrix$~M$.

Comment: Think about what the action of $M$ is on the plane, and then try to relate that to the modulus and argument of its complex eigenvalues. See also my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1546104/265466).