# Markov Matrix with complex eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

What properties does a Markov matrix (with real entries) with complex eigenvalues have?

For example, consider this matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

If I start in the state $(1,0,0)^T$, this does not have a steady state, right?

Comment: What do complex eigenvalues of _any_ real matrix indicate? See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1546104/265466) for one explanation.

Comment: If in a Markov Matrix the sum of the columns is $1$, then the dominant eigenvalue is $1$ and the other eigenvalues (complex or real) are irrelevant. An eigenvector of eigenvalue $1$ is responsible for the Steady State

Comment: If I start in the state $(1,0,0)^T$, I will not reach a steady state, right?

Comment: I assume the Markov Matrix is a regular matrix, meaning one can leave from any state and arrive in any state, and ignoring "funny" examples like having only $1$'s and $0$'s in the matrix.  Then the initial state doesn't matter, one will obtain the same Steady State.Moreover, in your provided example, did you calculate the eigenvalues?